# How to use a boolean outside the scope of a key listener

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, keylistener

I created a shop cart login JFrame and I added a "shopkeeperToggle" so that when it's pressed the user logs in to the shopkeeper's JFrame and otherwise to a shopper's jframe. the problem is I don't know how to implement it, I tried to set a boolean "pressed" to false whenever the key is released in the "shopkeeperToggle" key listener, and apparently I'm unable to use the value of pressed inside the sign-in button.

Here's the code for the toggle:

```
    shopkeeperToggle = new JToggleButton("Shopkeeper");
    shopkeeperToggle.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            pressed = false;
        }
    });
```

and this is what I'm trying to do in the sign in button:

```
signinButton = new JButton("Sign in ");
    signinButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             try {
                        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/shoppingCart","root","");
                        // select the users that have the inputted credentials from the database
                        String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userUsername = ? AND userEmail =?AND userPassword = ? ";
                    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    ps.setString(1,usernamelogin.getText());
                    ps.setString(2, emaillogin.getText());
                    ps.setString(3,passwordlogin.getText());
                    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    // if query executed and 
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        // if login succ show window log succ, and go to home shopping page
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Login successful! :)");
/////////////////this is where I fail////////////////////
                            if (pressed) {
                                OwnerHomePage ownerhome = new OwnerHomePage();
                                ownerhome.setVisible(true);
                                setVisible(false);
                            } else {
                                UserHomePage home = new UserHomePage();
                                home.setVisible(true);
                                setVisible(false);
                            }
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong Username or Email or Password :(");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e1);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: `boolean pressed = signinButton.isSelected();`

Comment: it friggin works you're a life saviour

Answer (score 0):

This may offer some help in fixing your issue. It is a fully compilable demo. The following changes were made.

- Used `Actions` in lieu of `KeyListener`.  A little more involved to setup but they can be configured to monitor only certain keys.
- Used a `JButton` in lieu of a `JToggleButton`.  No specific reason and can be changed.
- Created separate inner classes for the listeners. Tends to reduce clutter and is usually more readable.
- Changed the name of the button depending on the mode.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ActionMapAndButtons {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities
                .invokeLater(() -> new ActionMapAndButtons().start());
    }

    public void start() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        MyClass cls = new MyClass();
        frame.add(cls);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MyClass extends JPanel {
    JButton button = new JButton("Shopper Sign in");
    boolean pause = false;

    public MyClass() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        add(button);
        InputMap map = getInputMap(WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            map.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke((char)i), "anyKey");
        }
        getActionMap().put("anyKey", new MyAction());
        setFocusable(true);

    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            Object obj = ae.getSource();
            if (obj instanceof JButton) {
                JButton b = (JButton) obj;
                pause = !pause;
                if (pause) {
                    b.setText("Shopkeeper Sign in");
                } else {
                    b.setText("Shopper Sign in");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class MyAction extends AbstractAction {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            String cmd = ae.getActionCommand();
            if (pause) {
                System.out.println("Shopkeeper - " + cmd);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Shopper - " + cmd);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Inner` (or `nested`) classes and `action` maps are covered in [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can define pressed as a static value;

```
class c {
    static boolean pressed = true;

    ...
}
```

and you can access anywhere;

```
c.pressed; //will return true if you don't change
```

Comment: I think the static is the best for outer access.

Comment: it's giving me an error that says "illegal modifier parameter"